# Add Callout-Block to incremental list in revealjs

Tags: quarto, reveal.js, callouts, incremental

I would like to add a `Callout Block` to a `{.incremental}` list in a slide using `revealjs`. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Callout Block in revealjs"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

::: {.incremental}

- Here some text

::: {.callout-tip}
## Tip with Title

This is an example of a callout with a title.
:::

:::
```

Output:

[image]

As we can see from the output, the callout block is not incremental like the text above. So I was wondering if it is possible to add callout blocks to an incremental list in revealjs Quarto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [quarto docs](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/#incremental-lists),

> By default number and bullet lists within slides are displayed all at once. You can override this globally using the `incremental` option.

So it seems **`.incremental` works for lists only**. But since you want the incremental behavior for both list items and callout blocks, consider using [`.fragment`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#fragments) instead,

> Fragments are used to highlight or incrementally reveal individual elements on a slide. Every element with the class fragment will be stepped through before moving on to the next slide.

```
---
title: "Callout Block in revealjs"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

::: {.fragment}

- Here some text

:::

::: {.fragment}

::: {.callout-tip}
## Tip with Title

This is an example of a callout with a title.
:::

:::
```